# Why does my program return an IndexError?

Tags: python

I am trying to write a function that will split a 500 line CSV file into 10 lines segments for further use but when the for loop reaches the end of the dataframe I get an `IndexError` that  `index 500 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 500` this error happens at `close_next` line I tried to use `try`,`except` but I get that same error this time at `open.append(float(pd[start][0]))` , I can't see my mistake and can't seem to fix this

```
ad = genfromtxt('BNBBTC.csv', delimiter=',' ,dtype=str)

### this flips the data frame and converts it into an array 
pd = np.flipud(ad)



def some_function(start, finish):
    open = []
    high = []
    low = []
    close = []
    volume = []
    date = []
    for x in range(finish-start):
        open.append(float(pd[start][0]))
        high.append(float(pd[start][1]))
        low.append(float(pd[start][2]))
        close.append(float(pd[start][3]))
        volume.append(float(pd[start][4]))
        date.append(pd[start][5])
        start = start + 1
        print ("start - finish " , start , finish)
    

    close_next = float(pd[finish][3])

    print (close_next)



iter = 0 

for x in range(len(pd)-5):
   some_function( iter, iter+10)
   iter = iter + 5
```

Comment: Please post the traceback message.

Comment: You do `range(len(pd)-5)` but then do `some_function(iter, iter+10)` .... should that be `+5`?

Comment: Did it work @sec-team ?

Comment: You have at least two mistakes. The first is that `some_function(iter, iter+10)` in general goes over the known size of `pd`. The second is is that "finish" is one past the bound you want, counting from zero. The first problem will appear to work on modulo 10 sizes such as 500, the second will likely always fail at the end of the list.

Comment: I assume you want to grab 5 items each time and process it. Since there are 500 items, you assume you are going to iterate through the loop 100 times. Do you think your code is doing that? Hint: Look at `for x in range(len(pd)-5)`. This is going to iterate how many times? Why dont you do `print (x)` and find out. You will that the change has to be done to tha section of the code. How many times is it actually iterating?  100 or 495?

Comment: @JoeFerndz you are almost right but I want to take 5 samples each time but with every new sample I change the position of the values inside sample in other words I shift 1 place forward

Comment: @SecTeam, so you want go in this sequence [0,1,2,3,4] then [1,2,3,4,5], then [2,3,4,5,6] ? If so,  why do you need var `iter`. You can just use `x`   And why do you want to send 10 items each time. If you do, then 495th item + 10 is out of range for the pd. Isn't. it?

Comment: I barely  wrote this how do you do it with x ?

Comment: can you elaborate in your question section what you see as the output. Also why do you have a for loop where the range is dynamic?  it has range(finish-start) and you are incrementing start by 1. You already know finish - start at start is 10. If you want to iterate only 5 times,  then why not make range (5). It will make it easy.

Comment: i meant range (10) and iterate thru it 10 times.

Answer (score 0):

Python arrays/lists are 0-indexed meaning that an array with length=500 will have a maximum index of 499 (0-499, inclusive).

Comment: how do fix this?

Comment: can you present how does pd looks like?

Comment: To me this reads like a homework assignment in an intro CS course, so I'm not going to give you a full solution. I suggest you look at the parameters to range() as you really don't want to increment by one each time like you are, you want to increment by 10 (or 5, it's hard to tell from your code vs your description).

Comment: also tell, are you getting just the error, or some output start-finish... then index eror?

Comment: The 500 is presumably the number of lines in the CSV, but that's kindof a random thing. There is no reason to hard code a 500 in the script. This answer needs to relate back to the question and an example would be a good way of doing that.

Answer (score 0):

after reading @tdelaney I changed the values in the bottom for loop and this seems to fix my problem

```
ad = genfromtxt('BNBBTC.csv', delimiter=',' ,dtype=str)

### this flips the data frame and converts it into an array 
pd = np.flipud(ad)






def some_function(start, finish):
    open = []
    high = []
    low = []
    close = []
    volume = []
    date = []
    for x in range(finish-start):
        open.append(float(pd[start][0]))
        high.append(float(pd[start][1]))
        low.append(float(pd[start][2]))
        close.append(float(pd[start][3]))
        volume.append(float(pd[start][4]))
        date.append(pd[start][5])
        start = start + 1
        print ("start - finish " , start , finish)
    

    close_next = float(pd[finish][3])

    print (close_next)



iter = 0

for x in range(len(pd)-5):
   some_function( iter, iter+5)
   iter = iter + 1
```

Comment: That looks good. You don't have to do the `iter` stuff because `x` is already 0, 1, 2... Also, I'm still not sure how `pd[finish]` works, on that final iteration it should still be 500. Maybe I'm seeing things....

Comment: I don't think it because the loop ends at 494 plus 5 you get 499

Comment: look at my comments. i have walked you thru the code line by line with values. it should help you understand what you are doing. This code has to be redone completely. I am not sure what you are trying to achieve. The logic needs. work

Answer (score 0):

This is not the answer to  the problem statement. However, I am going to point out areas that may need some work in your code.

**Below is original code. by. Sec Team** with my comments

```
def some_function(start, finish):
    open = []    #please dont use open, close, and date as a variable
    high = []    #you are initializing all these lists to empty list
    low = []     #each time it comes into the function
    close = []   #you are not returning the lists back from the function
    volume = []  #nor are you assigning the values from these lists 
    date = []    #to any global variables. so what happens after you
                 #have processed all these values? You throw them away?

    for x in range(finish-start): 
        #if you ignore all the code below except start = start + 1
        #and just print x, finish, and start, you will find that this loop
        #iterates only 10 times. So why not give range(10)?

        open.append(float(pd[start][0]))
        high.append(float(pd[start][1]))
        low.append(float(pd[start][2]))
        close.append(float(pd[start][3]))
        volume.append(float(pd[start][4]))
        date.append(pd[start][5])

        start = start + 1
        print ("start - finish " , start , finish)

        #since this loop runs 10 times, you get 10 print statements
        #where start increments each time and gets closer finish
        #the final iteration ends at 1 less than finish
        #When x = 0 (first call), start & finish values will be 0,10 then 1,10 then 2,10.... 9,10
        #When x = 1 (second call), start & finish values will be 5,15 then 6,15 then 7,15... 14,15
        #it will keep iterating thru the loop a few times
        #when x = 98 (99th call), start & finish values will be 490, 500.
        #The values for the 99 call time will be (490, 500), (491, 500),
        #(492, 500), .... (499,500)
        #you are only on your 99th call (x = 98)
        #remember: your for loop for x expects you to go thru till 495
        #this loop goes successfully as you are referring to [start] variable

    #when you come to this point, the value for finish is 500
    #The range for pd is 0 thru 499 (per your original comment. It has only 500 rows
    #the code will break here because we don't have pd[500][3]
    #Is this what you were expecting to do? I am not sure what you are trying to do
    #hopefully by showing you what's happening inside your loop, it helps you understand
    #where to fix your code

    close_next = float(pd[finish][3])

    print (close_next)

iter = 0 

for x in range(len(pd)-5):
    some_function( iter, iter+10)
    iter = iter + 5

#as I told you, the for loop is sending values to some_function the wrong way
#the start and finish values may need to change or your implementation
#has to change. Whatever it is , you need to rework the entire code to 
#ensure it does not go to IndexError
```

Hope this helps you understand how your code works.